# How to count each date value in between statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
SELECT COUNT(VALUE) 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE ID ='ID' 
AND BETWEEN 'DATE1' AND 'DATE2'
```

- It will give total count value for the specified date

But I need the count for each date how to do that...eg date is 1/1/2012 to 4/1/2012....I need count for each date like 1,2,3,4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), YourDate, 101), COUNT(VALUE) 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE ID ='ID' 
AND Yourdate BETWEEN 'DATE1' AND 'DATE2'
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), YourDate, 101)
```

The catch using dates is to get rid of the time part. Using `CONVERT` with style 101 does just that.